# Where to put theme file when using the gatsby-plugin-material-ui with gatsby?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I can't seem to get my theme file to have any effect on my components in a Gatsby app. I'm using [gatsby-plugin-material-ui](https://github.com/hupe1980/gatsby-plugin-material-ui)

relevant part of `gatsby-config.js`

```
 `gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-material-ui`,
      options: {
        pathToTheme: 'src/theme.js',
      },
```

`theme.js`

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

import indigo from '@material-ui/core/colors/indigo';
import pink from '@material-ui/core/colors/pink';
import red from '@material-ui/core/colors/red';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: indigo,
    secondary: pink,
    error: red,
  },
  spacing: {
      100
  }
})


export default theme;
```

within the component:

```
imports...
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const styles = theme => ({
  heroText: {
    color:'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
    lineHeight:7
  },
  mainBlogCopy: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit,
    backgroundColor:theme.palette.primary
  },
});

export default withStyles(styles)(AboutPage);
```

`package.json`

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.3",
    "gatsby": "^2.3.24",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.0.34",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.0.24",
    "gatsby-plugin-material-ui": "^1.2.4",
```

more...

How does one use a theme in another file with this plugin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a file maybe named `mui-root-wrapper.js` at your root directory

```
// mui-root-wrapper.js

import React from 'react'
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import theme from './src/theme.js'

export default ({ element }) => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    {element}
  </ThemeProvider>
)
```

Then import this component to both `gatsby-browser.js` and `gatsby-ssr.js`:

```
// gatsby-browser.js, gatsby-ssr.js

import muiRootWrapper from "./mui-root-wrapper"
export const wrapRootElement = muiRootWrapper
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in mui-root-wrapper.js

I had to do

    import theme from './src/theme.js' 

for the file to be found by webpack. Otherwise I was getting the error

    Generating SSR bundle failed
    
    Can't resolve 'src/theme.js' in '/app'
    
    File: mui-root-wrapper.js